# Why mysql server stills stopped after 'brew services start mysql'?

Tags: mysql, homebrew

brew services restart mysql

```
==> Successfully stopped `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
```

brew services list

```
Name  Status   User File
mysql stopped  me   ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Same with mariadb.

Can `/usr/local/var/mysql` content influence someway?